# The TableFilterDemo.java is not working

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I am learning how to add filter to JTable, so I found tutorials in sun website

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/examples/components/TableFilterDemoProject/src/components/TableFilterDemo.java

I copied the code to netbeans, the code complied and run successfully, but when I enter "jane" in filtertext the table data just disappears instead of showing that row.

Looking for help thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's case sensitive. Type "Jane"

Good luck

**UPDATE**

If you want to make it case insensitive the (?i) works fine before the Regex so change this line

```
rf = RowFilter.regexFilter(filterText.getText(), 0);
```

like this.

```
rf = RowFilter.regexFilter("(?i)"+ filterText.getText(), 0);
```

Good luck!

Comment: I required 15 reputation, so I couldnt vote up, I will do that when I get the reputation.